# doctrine2 multiple level inheritance (4-5)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to create 4 level inheritance in doctrine2 ?

Something like:

```
/**
     * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
     */   
     class Person{

    }

/**
 * 
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({'man_in_black'="ManInBack"})
 */
        class Man extends Person{

    }
    /**
    *??????????????
    */
    class ManInBlack extends Man{

    }


    /*
*@ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity()
*/
        class Bob extends ManInBlack{

    }
```

I can't understand what exactly should be instead of "?????????????"

Comment: I'm so sorry,  I meant table inheritance using doctrine.

Comment: My gut feeling is that it's not possible and I cannot see any documentation anywhere that suggests otherwise.

Comment: So you want to end up with three tables? man <- man_in_black <- bob?  Like @Darragh I don't see how that can work especially since you need to hard code class names (like Bob) in the discriminator map.  I suppose you could try putting in discriminator mapping in your ManInBlack and see what happens.

Comment: In my project i've created such structure. It didn't work untill i empty my database and load migrations. Now it seems to be working. So instead of "?????" I simply inserted    /*
*@ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity()
*/                and in DiscriminatorMap of class Man i discribed all descendants